# Delete the zip files with date format by comparing to the present date in Python

Tags: python, date, dir

I have a list of files(Actually these are the files in some directory) as below for example

```
import os
path  = '/home/user/folder'
files = os.listdir(path)
```

so result is as below

```
files = ['backup_file_2010-06-30_category.zip','backup_file_2010-06-28_category.zip',
         'backup_file_2010-06-26_category.zip','backup_file_2010-06-24_category.zip',
         'backup_file_2010-06-23_category.zip','backup_file_2010-06-20_category.zip'
         'some_text_files_one.txt','some_text_files_two.txt']
```

so from this list i need to delete the zip files that contains the date in it on a condition that,  `the files that are created before five days from today needs to be deleted`

I mean if the file created today is `backup_file_2013-04-17_category.zip`, we need to delete the files that are created before five days from today something like the files named as `backup_file_2013-04-11_category.zip`

Can anyone please let me know how to do this in python

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like that and in the `filtered_files` list you have the list of files that need to be deleted. It works if your backup files starting with `prefix`.

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import os

path  = '/home/user/folder'
files = os.listdir(path)

prefix = 'backup_file_'
days = 5

filtered_files = []
five_days_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=days)
date_before = '%s%s' % (prefix, five_days_ago.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
for f in files:
  if f.startswith(prefix) and f < date_before:
    filtered_files.append(f)

print filtered_files
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime, os
mydaterange=[datetime.datetime.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(1,6)]
myfilenames=['backup_file_'+ str(x.year)+'-'+ str(x.month) + '-' + str(x.day)+ '_category.zip' for x in mydaterange]
for files in os.listdir('/home/user/folder'):
    if files.endswith('.zip') and files.startswith('backup_file_'):
        if files not in myfilenames:
            os.remove(files)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the date from each filename using a regex, and compare it to see if the backup file is indeed old. If there is no match from the regex then it's not a backup file.

```
from datetime import date
import re

OLD_FILE_DAYS = 5

def is_old_backup_file(filename, today):
    m = re.match('backup_file_(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)_category.zip', filename)
    if not m:
        return False
    year, month, day = (int(s) for s in m.groups())
    d = date(year, month, day)
    delta = today - d
    return delta.days > OLD_FILE_DAYS

files = ['backup_file_2010-06-30_category.zip','backup_file_2010-06-28_category.zip',
         'backup_file_2010-06-26_category.zip','backup_file_2010-06-24_category.zip',
         'backup_file_2010-06-23_category.zip','backup_file_2010-06-20_category.zip',
         'some_text_files_one.txt','some_text_files_two.txt'] # os.listdir(path)

today = date(2010, 7, 1) # date.today()

filtered_files = [f for f in files if not is_old_backup_file(f, today)]

print filtered_files
```

Output:

```
['backup_file_2010-06-30_category.zip', 'backup_file_2010-06-28_category.zip',
'backup_file_2010-06-26_category.zip', 'some_text_files_one.txt',
'some_text_files_two.txt']
```